# Volkswagen Radio Problems

Tags: battery, vw, audio

I have a 2002 Volkswagen Jetta GLS.  Recently My battery died & I had to replace it.  Since then my Radio doesn't work. It wont come on or go off.
It just reads PHONE.  Please help!! What can I do? Any help will be so greatly appreciated. (I'm tired of singing to myself!!)

Comment: Who replaced the battery?  Did a store or shop do it or was it you?  Maybe try to disconnect the battery for 10 minutes and hook it back up to "reset" the radio.  Also, could it need a security code entered?

Comment: I replaced the battery. I've already diconnected battery & etc.    And I can't enter a radio code because it wont go to Safe mode.  it only says PHONE. It wont turn on or off either.

Answer (score 1):

Try holding both MODE and SCAN buttons at the same time.  The radio should display *1000* at some point.  Release the buttons and use the numbered station preset buttons to enter your code.

Let us know if this works, or not.

Comment: I don't see a mode button on my radio.  Its a factory volkswagen one.

Comment: It only says PHONE. it wont turn on or off. the only thing I can see except Phone is when I turn the volume up or down.  It still doesn't work though.

Comment: @CountryGirl - did you ever get this resolved?